# How to convert JalaliDate to GregorianDate in yii2?

Tags: date, yii2, jalali-calendar

I want to convert jalali to gregorian. In input is taken in the jalali date
in view :

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'start_date')->widget(jDate\DatePicker::className())->textInput() ?>
```

**controller**:

```
 $jstartdate = $model->start_date; // string(10) "1395/06/15"
```

Now I want to store in database with gregorian format ("2016-09-05").
Which function in jalali class does this work?
I used many function for example `createFromFormat` or `toGregorian`. but I did not get result.

Answer (score 4):

For an easy way, you must have `intl` extension installed on your server and your php version must be higher that `5.4`. If it is, you easily can make an `IntlCalendar` instance with Persian calendar parameters:

```
$date = IntlCalendar::createInstance(
    'Asia/Tehran',
    'fa_IR@calendar=persian'
);
```

set your datetime:

```
$date->set(1395, 5, 15, 19, 17, 11); // Notice that month number begin from 0 not 1.
```

then make an instance of `IntlDateFormatter` with Gregorian calendar -or every calendar you want:

```
$intlDateFormatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
    "en_US", // string $locale
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL, // int $datetype
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL, // int $timetype
    'Asia/Tehran', // mixed $timezone
    IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN, // mixed $calendar
    'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss' // string $pattern
);
```

and use `toDateTime` method of that for showing your desired date:

```
var_dump($intlDateFormatter->format($date));
// /srv/http/test/DateTime.php:29:
// string(19) "2016/09/05 19:17:11"
```

P.S.: I write a small library for converting date that can be found here: https://github.com/meysampg/intldate, Also if you only want to represent date on other system, you can use [IntlDateBehavior](https://github.com/meysampg/yii2-intldatebehavior).

Comment: dont work. i tested, 1396/03/31 to 2017-07-22 , it's not correct

Comment: I will check it! Can you open an issue about the bug? It's hard to  reproduce with this level of information. @user3770797

Comment: The new value for IntlCalendar::FIELD_DAY_OF_MONTH. The month sequence is zero-based, i.e., January is represented by 0, February by 1, …, December is 11 and Undecember (if the calendar has it) is 12.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/intlcalendar.set.php

Answer (score 4):

Since Yii 2.0.7:

```
Yii::$app->formatter->locale = 'fa_IR@calendar=persian';
Yii::$app->formatter->calendar = \IntlDateFormatter::TRADITIONAL;
Yii::$app->formatter->timeZone = 'UTC';
$value = 1451606400; // Fri, 01 Jan 2016 00:00:00 (UTC)
echo Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($value, 'php:Y');
// outputs "۱۳۹۴"
```